# get static length substring

Tags: c#, regex, substring

**Edit[20140203 2143]**
I have a string `0.00,0.00,0.00,"0.00","AID000000000",0.00,0,0` and I want to get value between leading `,"AID` and trailing `",`, these values never change.

What regex should look like in c#? (I'm newbie in regex field)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This Regex should work:

```
(?<=,"AID)[0-9]+(?=",)
```

This uses [lookaheads and lookbehinds](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to match the numbers in between `,"AID` and `",`

You can try it out here: http://www.rubular.com/r/T0RBuqh9JX

Comment: Yes, the lookaheads and lookbehinds was what I was actually looking for. CHeers.

Answer (score 2):

With Regex:

```
var reg = new Regex(@"\d+");
var numbersOnly = reg.Match(yourString).Value;
```

You can also do it with LINQ, by stripping out all non-numeric characters:

```
var numbersOnly = new string(yourString.Where(char.IsNumber).ToArray());
```

In both cases, the result is:

```
"0000000000"
```

*(I'm assuming you want the result in a string.)*

Comment: Will it work if the actual string is something like this `0.00,0.00,0.00,"0.00","AID000000000",0.00,0,0` ?

Comment: Yeah it looks like delimiter problem, but actually I just wanted to know how I can get values between static values.